# Process PCD files (Delete lines based on indices) - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fwrite, point-cloud-library

I have a *.pcd file(see below). The data has five fields and the last field is 'index'. Now I want to delete points with index [2 4 6 8]. And write the result to a new .pcd file....
Does anyone know how to do it ...... 
Thanks a lot!

```
   # .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
   FIELDS x y z rgb index
   SIZE 4 4 4 4 4
   TYPE F F F F U 
   COUNT 1 1 1 1 1
   WIDTH 12
   HEIGHT 1
   VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
   POINTS 12
   DATA ascii
   1824.064 -627.111 -119.4176 0 1
   1824.412 -629.678 -119.7147 0 2    %delete
   1819.929 -630.5591 -116.9839 0 3
   1820.276 -623.1166 -117.2799 0 4   %delete
   1820.622 -635.6741 -117.576 0 5
   1816.134 -636.5178 -114.8408 0 6   %delete
   1816.48 -639.0659 -115.1358 0 7
   1811.02 -639.5347 -111.7907 0 8    %delete
   1811.364 -662.0717 -112.0844 0 9
   1707.098 829.5436 59.0613 0 10
   1707.441 827.0067 58.76764 0 11
   1707.785 824.4698 58.47398 0 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
exclude_index = [2 4 6 8];
field_num = 5;

A = importdata(inputfile,'\n');

A1 = cellfun(@(x) strtrim(x), A,'Uni',0);
A1_firstchar = arrayfun(@(x) A1{x}(1),1:numel(A1),'Uni',0);
startind = find(cell2mat(isstrprop(A1_firstchar,'digit')),1,'first');

A_part1 = A(1:startind-1);
A_part2 = A(startind:end,:);

B = cellfun(@(x) strtrim(x),A_part2 ,'Uni',0);
C = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x),B,'Uni',0);
D = str2double(arrayfun(@(n) C{n}(field_num),1:numel(C)));

Anew = [A_part1 ; A_part2(~ismember(D,exclude_index),:)];

fid = fopen(outputfile, 'w');
for i=1:numel(Anew)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', Anew{i});
end
fclose(fid);
```

Please make sure to edit `inputfile` and `outputfile` to the paths where you have the input `.pcd` file and the path where you intend to save the processed `.pcd` file respectively.

---

### Performance oriented solution

```
%// Number of header lines
headerlines = 10;

%// read data into cell array
A = importdata(inputfile,'\n');

%// read formatted data
fid = fopen(inputfile, 'r');
C = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %d %d','HeaderLines',headerlines,'Delimiter',' ');

%// removed rows from cell array that matches our conditions
idx = find(ismember(C{5},[2 4 6 8]));
A(headerlines + idx)=[];

%// Write to output file
fid = fopen(outputfile, 'w');
for i=1:numel(A)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', A{i});
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well! While when the amount of the point cloud is huge, the speed is a little slow.... do you think there is possibly some faster method....

Comment: @guodi There could be few methods. To start off, do you know the number of header lines that we can skip for those pcd files? Is that a constant for all pcd files that you would be working with? That way we can skip code until the calculation of `startind`.

Comment: Yes! The **startind** for all the pcd files are the same.

Comment: @guodi See how the newly added approach works for you?

Comment: It works pretty well. The _textscan_ really saves time! Thanks!